# Rstudio view（） dataframe display nothing

Tags: view, rstudio

After I upated Rstudio to 1.0.153, I can't view dataframe by function view().
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwdGR.jpg)
then I updated Rstudio1.1.383, the problem still exists.
I reinstalled the Rstudio, the problem still exists.
My system is windows10
Thank you.

Comment: See also [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007743908-The-Rstudio-view-not-work-just-blank-) support question.

Comment: Thank you, this problem confused me a lot of time, but after I read your comment, the Rstudio suddenly corrected. That's interesting.